# Unable to start MySQL service in docker during gitlab-ci

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following `.gitlab-ci` taken from the example of [Laravel Dusk CI](https://github.com/chilio/laravel-dusk-ci/tree/master/examples):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

# Variables
variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql

build:
  stage: build
  services:
     - mysql:5.7

  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
  script:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    # - npm install # if you need to install additional modules from your projects package.json
    # - npm run dev # if you need to run dev scripts for example laravel mix 
  cache:
      key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
      paths:
        # these are only examples, you should modify them according to your project, 
        # or remove cache routines entirely, if they are causing any problems on your next builds..
        # below are 2 safe ones if you use composer install and npm install in your stage script
        - vendor
        - node_modules
         # - /resources/assets/vendors  # for example if you put your vendor node-libraries there

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
      - vendor
      - node_modules
    policy: pull
    
  services:
    - mysql:5.7

  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    # - cp phpunit.xml.ci phpunit.xml # if you are using custom config for your phpunit tests in CI
    - configure-laravel
    - start-nginx-ci-project
    - ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -v --coverage-text --colors --stderr
    # - phpunit -v --coverage-text --colors --stderr # if you want to use preinstalled phpunit
    - php artisan dusk --colors --debug

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs # for debugging
      - ./tests/Browser/screenshots
      - ./tests/Browser/console
    expire_in: 7 days
    when: always
```

However, when the runner executes the job, I keep getting the following warning:

```
Using Docker executor with image chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable ...
Starting service mysql:5.7 ...
Pulling docker image mysql:5.7 ...
Using docker image sha256:66bc0f66b7af6ba3ea96582685d3afcd6dff93c2f8999da0ffadd67b280db548 for mysql:5.7 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner-237f18d2-project-23-concurrent-0-mysql-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
ContainerStart: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-237f18d2-project-23-concurrent-0-mysql-0 AS /runner-237f18d2-project-23-concurrent-0-mysql-0-wait-for-service/service

Service container logs:
2018-07-11T19:49:03.214991318Z 
2018-07-11T19:49:03.215062485Z ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
2018-07-11T19:49:03.215067480Z command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
2018-07-11T19:49:03.215070774Z 
2018-07-11T19:49:03.215073778Z mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot stat shared object: Permission denied
```

I've tried to set the runner to privileged in the **config.toml**:

```
privileged = true
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the Question:

**mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot stat shared object: Permission denied**

- Step1: update your software and kernel(maybe):

  `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
- Step2: install the docker dependency package:

  - (ubuntu/debian):  `apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software properties-common`
  - (centos/redhat):`yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2`
- Step3: reboot your server & restart your docker-ce:

  `reboot`

  `systemctl restart docker-ce`